# Flutter Web error : :Unsupported operation: Platform._version:

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api

Greetings iam working on a flutter app( mobile + web + desktop)
my backend is asp.net core
when iam trying to call my API (on mobile and desktop) it works perfectly but when I am calling from the web (chrome) iam get this error

```
Unsupported operation: Platform._version
```

my question is it something related to flutter or asp.net core
i really did some research but none helped can someone help me in that

Comment: Can you post more of the error? So it's clearer what may be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all idea is to enable CORS on the web api
here is what you need to do
in Startup.cs Go to ConfigureServices and add this code

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder => {
                    builder
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowAnyOrigin();
               });
        });
```

now in the Configure method add this code

```
  app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

also in every controller you need to add   [EnableCors]
this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely related to using dart:io which is not compatible with web.

If you post the full stack trace we can get a better idea.

Try using https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io instead or even better https://pub.dev/packages/dio